# KinectColorViewer SDK 1.7

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to make KinectColorViewer to work with SDK 1.7 but without success. I can display video picture only if I manually copy pixels from camera to Image element.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"
  xmlns:WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers" x:Class="KinectD.Camera"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
Title="Camera">

<Grid>
    <k:KinectUserViewer k:KinectRegion.KinectRegion="{Binding ElementName=kinectRegion}" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <k:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="sensorChooserUi" />

    <k:KinectRegion x:Name="kinectRegion">
        <Grid>
            <k:KinectCircleButton Label="Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="MenuButtonOnClick" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="Images/smile.png" Height="30"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </k:KinectCircleButton>

        </Grid>
    </k:KinectRegion>
    <WpfViewers:KinectColorViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" Kinect="{Binding ElementName=sensorChooserUi, Mode=OneWay, Path=Kinect}"/>


</Grid>
```

And XAML.CS:

```
public partial class Camera : Page
{
    #region "Kinect"
    private KinectSensorChooser sensorChooser;
    #endregion

    public Camera()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        // initialize the sensor chooser and UI
        this.sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();
        //Assign the sensor chooser with the sensor chooser from the mainwindow. 
        //We are reusing the sensorchoosing declared in the first window that can in contact with kinect
        this.sensorChooser = Generics.GlobalKinectSensorChooser;
        //subscribe to the sensorChooserOnKinectChanged event
        this.sensorChooser.KinectChanged += SensorChooserOnKinectChanged;
        //Assign Kinect Sensorchooser to the sensorchooser we got from our static class
        this.sensorChooserUi.KinectSensorChooser = sensorChooser;
        // Bind the sensor chooser's current sensor to the KinectRegion
        var regionSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.kinectRegion, KinectRegion.KinectSensorProperty, regionSensorBinding);
    }

    private void SensorChooserOnKinectChanged(object sender, KinectChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        bool error = false;
        if (args.OldSensor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                args.OldSensor.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Default;
                args.OldSensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = false;
                args.OldSensor.DepthStream.Disable();
                args.OldSensor.SkeletonStream.Disable();

                args.OldSensor.ColorStream.Disable();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // KinectSensor might enter an invalid state while enabling/disabling streams or stream features.
                // E.g.: sensor might be abruptly unplugged.
                error = true;
            }
        }

        if (args.NewSensor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                args.NewSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
                args.NewSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
                args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                error = true;
                // KinectSensor might enter an invalid state while enabling/disabling streams or stream features.
                // E.g.: sensor might be abruptly unplugged.
            }
        }

        if (!error)
            kinectRegion.KinectSensor = args.NewSensor;
    }

    private void MenuButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Unsubscribe to the sensorchooser's  event SensorChooseronkinectChanged
        this.sensorChooser.KinectChanged -= SensorChooserOnKinectChanged;
        (Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("_mainFrame") as Frame).Source = new Uri("MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

In tutorial I was following (http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Camera-Fundamentals) instructor just drops KinectColorViewer to a screen, sets path and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The `KinectColorViewer` available in the `KinectWpfViewers` assembly is used in the "Kinect Explorer" example, and that is the best place to see how it is used and behaves.  From this example you will find that the proper way to initialize the viewer in the XAML and the bindings that are necessary.

From the code you posted, you appear to binding the Kinect itself (a reference to the hardware) to the `KinectColorViewer`, which is not what it is expecting.  You need to be setting a reference to a `KinectSensorManager` class, which is part of the `KinectWpfViewers` assembly.

Here is a simplified XAML with a `KinectColorViewer`

```
<Window x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.KinectExplorer.KinectWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.KinectExplorer"
        xmlns:kt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers"
        Title="Kinect Explorer" Width="812" Height="768">
    <Grid>
        <kt:KinectColorViewer x:Name="ColorViewer" KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" CollectFrameRate="True" RetainImageOnSensorChange="True" />
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

Then you XAML.CS constructor will look something similar to:

```
public KinectWindow()
{
    this.viewModel = new KinectWindowViewModel();

    // The KinectSensorManager class is a wrapper for a KinectSensor that adds
    // state logic and property change/binding/etc support, and is the data model
    // for KinectDiagnosticViewer.
    this.viewModel.KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();

    Binding sensorBinding = new Binding("KinectSensor");
    sensorBinding.Source = this;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.viewModel.KinectSensorManager, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, sensorBinding);

    // Attempt to turn on Skeleton Tracking for each Kinect Sensor
    this.viewModel.KinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;

    this.DataContext = this.viewModel;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Review the "Kinect Explorer" example for complete details.

Comment: Thanks but for that element receive a message: `The member "Kinect Sensor Manager" is not recognized or is not accessible.` I've read somewhere that I can do it without using that element in 1.7. I've just began learning so maybe I mixed something up :)

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  Make sure you are initializing the manager and setting it up properly -- use the "Kinect Explorer" for guidance.  I looked at the code for the `KinectColorViewer` and do not see anything to suggest that it doesn't require the `KinectSensorManager`; the base `KinectControl` class still uses the manager very extensively.  Where did you read it was no longer required?

Comment: Thank you. I saw it is done with `KinectSensorManager` but I've done it a little bit differently. If I understand correctly, it can be done on that way I posted? It was a small mistake, they changed the way to access path in 1.7 or 1.6 probably because in other tutorials it looks like this. I will post what I changed.

Comment: I confused by your last comment.  Is it fixed, or are you still having the problem?  You *must*, to my knowledge, bind the `KinectSensorManager` dependency property of the `KinectColorViewer` in order for it to work.  This is true in SDK 1.6 and I haven't noticed anything in SDK 1.7 that suggests it has changed.  Unless you've modified the `KinectColorViewer` you must bind the `KinectSensorManager`.

Comment: I changed that line for `KinectColorViewer` to this:         `<WpfViewers:KinectColorViewer HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="240" Width="320" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Kinect="{Binding ElementName=sensorChooserUi, Path=KinectSensorChooser.Kinect, Mode=OneWay}"/>`. It's working well now. The problem was in path. I didn't need to change anything in my code. In couple of tutorials it was just `Path=Kinect`. I don't know is this the good way to do it but it's working fine now. I don't know why I can't access `KinectSensorManager`.

Comment: That's just weird.  I'm glad it is working for you, but I am scratching my head over how (I need to sit down w/ my Kinect to test this).  `KinectColorViewer` extends `KinectViewer`, which extends `KinectControl`... none of these has a `Kinect` DP and all classes have directly reference the `KinectSensorManager` or its events.  I must be missing something in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with using KinectSensorManager. It turns out you need to call to Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.Wpf.Viewers and not just the kinect.dll, kinect.toolkit.dll, and kinect.controls.dll.
However, when I implemented KinectSensorManager, then the KinectUI and SensorChooser stopped working on my xaml interface.